# How to make my pandas script export to csv

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have managed to get the output I want from this script:

[image]

But I am having trouble exporting it to a csv using:

```
v.to_csv(n + '.csv', index=False)
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): Python/CouponRedemptions/start.py", line 22, in <module> print(v['invoice_line_normal_price']) File "~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2902, in getitem indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key) File "~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2893, in get_loc raise KeyError(key) from err KeyError: 'invoice_line_normal_price'
```

I think it is the way the DF is structured, you cannot export it in its current state. I was wondering how I would go about making this work or any suggestions on where I cant start looking.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

r = pd.read_csv('cp.csv', low_memory=False)

r = r.filter(['shop_name','order_coupon_code','invoice_line_type','invoice_date','invoice_line_normal_price'])
r = r[r.order_coupon_code.notnull()]
r['invoice_line_normal_price'] = pd.to_numeric(r['invoice_line_normal_price'],errors = 'coerce')

n = input("Enter the coupon name: ")
nr = r[r.order_coupon_code.str.match(n,flags=re.IGNORECASE)]
nr = nr[nr.invoice_line_type.str.match('charge')]
nr = nr.sort_values('shop_name')
v = nr.groupby(['shop_name'])['invoice_line_normal_price'].value_counts().to_frame('counts')
print(v)
```

Comment: what's the output of print(v)?

Comment: try `v.to_csv(n + '.csv', index=False)`

Comment: Hi @ShubhamPeriwal, I have updated the output of print(v) in the question.

Comment: yep I meant try `try v.reset_index().to_csv(n + '.csv', index=False)`. Sorry I missed that in my previous comment

Answer (score 0):

example of csv code

```
shop_name order_coupon_code invoice_line_type             invoice_date  invoice_line_normal_price  moresome moreother hello
0     shop1              nv55              sell  01.01.2016 01:00:00.000                       15.0         3        tt    hi
1     shop2              nv44             quote  01.01.2016 02:00:00.000                       22.0         4        rr   hey
2     shop3              nv22            charge  01.01.2016 03:00:00.000                       27.0         5        dd  what
```

```py
mport pandas as pd

# The low_memory option is not properly deprecated, but it should be, since it does not actually do anything differently
r = pd.read_csv('cp.csv')
print(r)

# r = r.loc[:,['shop_name', 'order_coupon_code', 'invoice_line_type', 'invoice_date', 'invoice_line_normal_price']]
r = r.filter(['shop_name','order_coupon_code','invoice_line_type','invoice_date','invoice_line_normal_price'])
r = r[r.order_coupon_code.notnull()]
r['invoice_line_normal_price'] = pd.to_numeric(r['invoice_line_normal_price'],errors = 'coerce')

# Enter the coupon name: nv22
n = input("Enter the coupon name: ")
nr = r[r.order_coupon_code.str.contains(n.lower())]

nr = nr[nr.invoice_line_type.str.match('charge')]
nr = nr.sort_values('shop_name')
v = nr.groupby(['shop_name'])['invoice_line_normal_price'].value_counts().to_frame('counts')
print(v)
v.to_csv(n + '.csv', index=False)
```

the output

```
shop_name invoice_line_normal_price        
shop3     27.0                            1
```

let say you need to add more to Single csv file

```py
v.to_csv(n + '.csv',mode='a', index=False)
```

no header

```py
v.to_csv(n + '.csv',mode='a', index=False,header=False)
```

just to make sure this error mean the name of column is not in your csv file check out the column name on your csv file

```
get_loc raise KeyError(key) from err KeyError: 'invoice_line_normal_price'
```

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I've updated the post to show the output from print(v)

Comment: I assumed that your CSV is similar to the one I created from a clear example. You have to type your order number in the input. I also assumed that your dataframe is in lowcase, otherwise you can add upper.

Comment: It seems to have exported to csv this time but it only exports counts column unfortunately.

Comment: add one line of csv file than can check first 2 lines